# NHIbernate: Mapping multiple rows in entity to single object representation

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Suppose I have the following schema:

Table: Showing
  showing_id
  movie_id
  theater_id
  show_date
  show_time

Table: Movie
  movie_id
  title
  ...

Table: Theater
  theater_id
  name
  ...

Is it possible to create a NHibernate mapping that would result in the following object hierarchy?

Theater
  - Movie
    -- List of Showings where each showing consists of
      -- Date
      -- Times (comma delimited string of times for the date)

Some sample data:

```
showing_id  movie_id    theater_id  show_date   show_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       1       2010-12-23  13:25
2       1       1       2010-12-23  15:25
3       1       1       2010-12-23  17:25
4       1       1       2010-12-23  19:25
5       1       1       2010-12-24  12:00
6       1       1       2010-12-24  14:45
```

For movie ID 1, I'd like this to map to a list of showing objects consisting of:
Showing 1: Date = 2010-12-23, Showtimes: 13:25, 15:25, 17:25, 19:25
Showing 2: Date = 2010-12-24, Showtimes: 12:00, 14:45

I'm assuming that I need to set the mappings using the standard NHibernate mapping conventions and then massage the raw data into the structure I'm looking for. I figured I'd double check and make sure there wasn't something I was missing out on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of. I would model this a many-to-many relationship with extra data (the showing). This is modeled as two one-to-many relationships. The classes would be:

```
Theater { TheaterId, Name, ..., IList<Showing> Showings }
Showing { ShowingId, Time, ..., Theater, Movie }
Movie { MovieId, Title, ..., IList<Showing> }
```